# Push notifications in ngCordova/Ionic, getting just "OK"

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, ionic-framework

I'm trying for the first time to create an hybrid app using [this example code for Android](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/pushNotifications/). I'm testing to see if I can get notifications to work and I'm getting two errors:

1. The `result` object you should get it doesn't contain anything but just OK
2. I'm getting `$rootScope is not defined`, where should I define it?

My code is

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

app.run(function($cordovaPush) {

  var androidConfig = {
    "senderID": "84xxxxxxxx",
  };

  document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
    $cordovaPush.register(androidConfig).then(function(result) {
      // Success
      console.log("OK, result is " + result);
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
      console.log("NOT OK");
    })

    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
      switch(notification.event) {
        case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
          }
          break;

        case 'message':
          // this is the actual push notification. its format depends on the data model from the push server
          alert('message = ' + notification.message + ' msgCount = ' + notification.msgcnt);
          break;

        case 'error':
          alert('GCM error = ' + notification.msg);
          break;

        default:
          alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
          break;
      }
    });


    // WARNING: dangerous to unregister (results in loss of tokenID)
    $cordovaPush.unregister(options).then(function(result) {
      // Success!
    }, function(err) {
      // Error
    })

  }, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include `$rootScope` in .run() like this

```
app.run(function($cordovaPush,$rootScope) {
```

And `result` in `register` response is not of any use to you.In case of success of registration you will receive an event `registered`, what you need is registration id, which you will receive here as `notification.regid`.

```
 case 'registered':
          if (notification.regid.length > 0 ) {
            alert('registration ID = ' + notification.regid);
          }
          break;
```

Comment: The documentation says that register() should return an object with data and not just a string with "OK".

Comment: @SandroAntonucci your concern is with device token, and for android you get key in part which i have mentioned, same is written in document. Please read document again.

Comment: For `ios` you get key key in register success callback , but for android you get it through event.